# How to append a local SVG image with D3.JS

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, append, href

I'm working with d3.js and I'm trying to append an image (svg or png) on my SVG, but the problem is, that I use xlink:href and I can't use local files. I need to use local files because my application will be only local.

Here's the code:

```
groupRectParent
        .append('svg:image')
            .attr('class', 'iconUserTotal')
            .attr('width', 10)
            .attr('height', 10)
            .attr('x', 5)
            .attr('y', -15)
            .attr('xlink:href', '/src/img/user.png')
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

[image: This is what is happening with my code] This is what is happening with my code

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Run a local webserver and serve the pages through that.

Comment: I'm actually running a local webserver but I dont understand what do you mean by "serve the pages through that". My application is a react JS server.

Comment: He is saying, that you can serve the static files, in this case the image, through the server using a normal url. Another thing you could do is, to just pack the svg into your code as a base64 encoded string and server the svg from that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to wasserholz for the answer, encode the SVG and use the string worked well. I just changed xlink:href to href and encoded my SVG.

```
groupRectParent
        .append('svg:image')
            .attr('class', 'iconUserTotal')
            .attr('width', 10)
            .attr('height', 10)
            .attr('x', 5)
            .attr('y', -15)
            .attr('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + encodedSVGString)
```